# Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference and how to resolved?

Tags: php, fatal-error

Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in /home2/-----/wp-content/plugins/affiliate-egg/XMLparser.php on line 63

Here is the relevant code:

```
61 function affegg_XML(){
62       $this->parser = &xml_parser_create();
63      xml_parser_set_option(&$this->parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, false);
64      xml_set_object(&$this->parser, &$this);
65      xml_set_element_handler(&$this->parser, 'open','close');
66      xml_set_character_data_handler(&$this->parser, 'data');}`
```

Comment: So, why did you put all those `&`?

Comment: Simple... log a bug with the plugin maintainer